# Call to onSaveInstanceState in activity when it goes into background (hidden)

Tags: view, bundle, viewgroup

I have a simple scenario where a Launch button from MainActivity launches a second Activity. In this second Activity, I add views dynamically per the user click, but when I go back to the main Activity and come back to the second activity, the added views aren't saved. What I found was whenever I press the home button and the onSaveInstanceState is called and when I come to the activity it is restored, however when I go the MainActivity, the onSaveInstanceState isn't called and the views are gone.

So I want to be able to know how to call to onSaveInstanceState() when activity goes into background hidden state. Or any other idea on how to save the ViewGroup

```
public class CountActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.counter_activity);
        container = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.counterContainer);
        sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        Log.d("TAG","CountActivity onCreate");
    }

    public void AddCounter(View view) {
        View parent = (View) view.getParent();
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater =
                (LayoutInflater) getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        final View addedView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_counter, null);
        container.addView(addedView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        Log.d("TAG", "CountActivity onSaveInstanceState");

    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        Log.d("TAG", "CountActivity onRestoreInstanceState");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        Log.d("TAG", "CountActivity onPause");
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestart() {
        super.onRestart();
        Log.d("TAG", "CountActivity onRestart");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Log.d("TAG", "CountActivity onResume");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.d("TAG", "CountActivity onDestroy");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        Log.d("TAG", "CountActivity onDestroy");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        Log.d("TAG", "CountActivity onStart");
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        Log.d("TAG", "CountActivity onConfigurationChanged");
    }
}
```

Comment: My full project code is https://github.com/biratrai/DynamicViews

Comment: Why don't you use sharespreferences?

Comment: @Aniruddha@Aniruddha: That doesn't help, I have to add a number of views on AddedCounter click, if it was only saving the value and stuff, it'd have worked. But, since I have to restore the number of views too, that doesn't help. You can check my project on github posted in comment above.